# Member function instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

The following compiles on GCC 4.8.1 (with `--std=c++11`):

```
struct non_default_constructible { non_default_constructible() = delete; };

template<class T>
struct dummy {
    T new_t() { return T(); }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    dummy<non_default_constructible> d;
    return 0;
}
```

The tricky part is that `dummy<non_default_constructible>::new_t()` is obviously ill-formed, but that does not prevent the compiler from instantiating `dummy<non_default_constructible>`.

Is this the behaviour specified by the standard? And what would be the relevant sections/keywords?

Comment: Since you never call d.new_t(); then the compiler doesn't try to compile the deleted constructor. If you add d.new_t(); to main does that cause a compile error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The member functions of a class template are instantiated only when required by a context, which means you will not see any error until you try to use `new_t()`. The related section from the C++ standard is:

> #### § 14.7.1 Implicit instantiation `[temp.inst]`
>
> 3. Unless a function template specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the **function template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist**. Unless a call is to a function template explicit specialization or to a member function of an explicitly specialized class template, a default argument for a function template or a member function of a class template is implicitly instantiated when the function is called in a context that requires the value of the default argument.
> 4. [ *Example:*
>
>    ```
>    template<class T> struct Z {
>      void f();
>      void g();
>    };
>
>    void h() {
>      Z<int> a;     // instantiation of class Z<int> required
>      Z<char>* p;   // instantiation of class Z<char> not required
>      Z<double>* q; // instantiation of class Z<double> not required
>      a.f();        // instantiation of Z<int>::f() required
>      p->g();       // instantiation of class Z<char> required, and
>                    // instantiation of Z<char>::g() required
>    }
>    ```
>
>    Nothing in this example requires `class Z<double>`, `Z<int>::g()`, or `Z<char>::f()` to be implicitly
>      instantiated. — *end example* ]

Comment: So in the standard's terminology, a member function of a template class is itself a (independent) template function?

Comment: It is more interesting why the code with `T new_t() { return T{}; }` implementation of `new_t` member function compiles even when `new_t` member function is called in the code ([clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02b6d6df1fdcde22), [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/beeb895a0eef5f65)).

Comment: @Constructor [no, it does not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13c4915e1d3edb49)

Comment: @PiotrS. I mean `T new_t() { return T{}; }` implementation (with braces, not brackets) as I wrote. See the references in my previous comment.

Comment: @Constructor Maybe `NonDefaultConstructable` is an aggregate despite the `=delete` default constructor, and as such `T{}` does aggregate initialization?  I remember some standard bug along those lines.  Also explains why `T()` doesn't work.

Comment: @Yakk As I remember it is not a bug but a feature. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @Constructor Bug is in the eye of the beholder.  ;)  The bug in my view in this case is that despite the programming clearly trying to block default construction `T{}` bypasses that.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, here is an extremely non-obvious behavior of the language.

Comment: @Constructor This bug is fixed for C++20

Comment: @user362515 Thank you! Could you provide a corresponding reference to the standard?

Comment: @Constructor "Prohibit aggregates with user-declared constructors (p1008r1)"

Comment: @user362515 Thank you very much! Good news!