# Why can a C++ template class access a private member of its base class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, private

With Visual Studio 2019 (v 16.7.3), I have found that a template class can access the private members of it non-template base class. Is this an expected behavior or is it a compiler bug?

When the derived class is not a template class, the private member of the base class is inaccessible as expected:

```
class A
{
};

class Base
{
public:
    Base() : m_pA(new A()) {}
private:
    A* m_pA;
};

class Derived :
    public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base() {}
    A* get_a() { return m_pA; }  // 'Base::m_pA': cannot access private member declared in class 'Base' 
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
}

== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==
```

However, if I make Derived a template class, it compiles without complaint:

```
template<class T>
class Derived :
    public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base() {}
    A* get_a() { return m_pA; }
};

int main()
{
    Derived<int> d;
}

== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==
```

Comment: Can you call get_a on the derived class

Comment: Clang successes to find the error [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4efMGEnzE) (even if not required).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [encapsulation and friend classes in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202742/encapsulation-and-friend-classes-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The posted code does not call `Derived<int>::get_a()` so that template member function does not get instantiated (and there is no "*access*" of the private parent member to speak of).

Adding the following `get_a()` call causes the same error as in the non-template case.

```
{
    Derived<int> d;
    d.get_a();  // error: 'A* Base::m_pA' is private within this context
}
```

---

[ *EDIT* ]   The implicit instantiation of template member functions (only) *when used* is ruled in the C++ standard under [temp.inst/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#4):

> *Unless a member of a templated class is a declared specialization,* ***the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced*** *in a context that requires the member definition to exist or if the existence of the definition of the member affects the semantics of the program;*

An explicit definition of the template specialization (though not just a declaration) will cause full instantiation of all members, resulting in the same error.

```
extern template class Derived<int>; // explicit declaration - ok

template class Derived<int>;        // explicit definition - error: 'A* Base::m_pA' is private within this context
```

---

[ *EDIT #2* ]   The argument was made in the comments (thanks [@Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42)) that the given code falls into the "*ill-formed, no diagnostic required*" category, meaning the compiler is allowed (though not required) to reject it on grounds that no possible (complete) instantiation of the class template `Derived<T>` can exist because of the `private` member access in `get_a()` *even if the member function is never used*.

This interpretation is based on the following section of [temp.res.general/6.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6):

> *The program is* ***ill-formed, no diagnostic required***, *if:*
>
> - ***no valid specialization*** *can be generated* ***for a template*** *or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated, or [...]*

- If "*valid specialization can be generated*" is taken to mean a complete *explicit* specialization of the entire template class, then the given code snippet is indeed "*ill-formed NDR*".
- If, however, "*valid specialization*" is understood to cover implicit specializations of the template class with (only) the required members as defined in [temp.inst/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#4) quoted earlier, then the given code snippet does not fall under "*ill-formed NDR*" because `get_a()` is never instantiated (per [temp.inst/11](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#11): "*an implementation* ***shall not implicitly instantiate*** *a function template, a variable template, a member template,* ***a non-virtual member function***, *a member class or static data member of a templated class, or a substatement of a constexpr if statement,* ***unless such instantiation is required***").

The linked [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4efMGEnzE) shows that `gcc` takes the latter interpretation, while `clang` the former.

In either case, the answer stands that if the template is not rejected upfront as  "*ill-formed NDR*" because of the no-valid-specializations-can-exist clause, then it will compile and work fine *as long as* `get_a()` does not get instantiated, either implicitly by direct reference, or by an explicit specialization of the template class.

Comment: Right.  It's important to remember what a template is - it's not code, it's *instructions* for generating the code once you have the template types filled in.  If there's no call to the function, no code gets generated and so no error gets generated.

Comment: Notice that the code is ill-formed NDR (as no valid instantiations might exist). clang successes to diagnose it :-) [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4efMGEnzE)

Comment: @Jarod42 That's interesting. A warning maybe, but I don't see why a hard error would be warranted there. The member function in question never gets instantiated in that snippet.

Comment: Hard error as there are no `U` such as `Derived<U>::get_a` is well formed. same as `static_assert(false);`. `m_pA` is not even dependent, so the check is relatively easy here.

Comment: @Jarod42 Maybe I am misreading it, but AFAICT there should be no check in this case because there is no instantiation. From [temp.inst/11](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#11): "*An implementation* ***shall not implicitly instantiate*** *a function template, a variable template, a member template,* ***a non-virtual member function***, *a member class or static data member of a templated class, or a substatement of a constexpr if statement,* ***unless such instantiation is required***".

Comment: [temp#res.general-6.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1) (and 6.4).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, I see. Though that says "*the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:* ***no valid specialization*** *can be generated* ***for a template*** *or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated*". However, the previous quote says that implicitly instantiating a ***template*** does not mean automatically instantiating  ***non-virtual member functions***. The example at [temp.inst/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#6) appears to support that ("*nothing ... requires Z<int>​::​g() ... to be implicitly instantiated*").

Comment: Related SO question: [Member function instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123254/member-function-instantiation).

Comment: I didn't say that `Derived<someT>::get_a` is/should be instantiated.
`dummy<int>::new_t()` is a valid possible instantiation, so `new_t` is not ill-formed.

Comment: @Jarod42 Guess it depends on how you read and piece together "*valid specialization*" against "*implicit instantiation*", though I'll leave that to the finer language lawyers. I added a 2nd edit to the question to (hopefully) summarize this. FWIW even clang doesn't appear to be entirely consistent about it, for example I'd have expected it to reject [this](https://godbolt.org/z/nonh9bMxh) for the same reason, but it does not.

Comment: NDR, It misses that opportunity. NDR applies mostly to hard/impossible to diagnose issue. I would says that this kind of diagnostic is just a bonus, as second pass will found the issue anyway, and we want to write code which is used.